# How do I set the order on WordPress Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I registered my Custom Post type like this

```
    register_post_type( 'projects',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Projects'),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Projects' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes' ),
        'menu_icon'=>'dashicons-portfolio',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_position'=>5,
        'supports' => array( 'thumbnail','title','editor' ),
    ) 
);
```

And I've added these functions,

```
/**
* add order column to admin listing screen for header text
*/
function add_new_projects_column($projects_columns) {
  $projects_columns['menu_order'] = "Order";
  return $projects_columns;
}
add_action('manage_projects_posts_columns', 'add_new_projects_column');


/**
* show custom order column values
*/
function show_order_column($name){
  global $post;

  switch ($name) {
    case 'menu_order':
      $order = $post->menu_order;
      echo $order;
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
}
add_action('manage_projects_posts_custom_column','show_order_column');


/**
* make column sortable
*/
function order_column_register_sortable($columns){
  $columns['menu_order'] = 'menu_order';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-projects_sortable_columns','order_column_register_sortable');
```

So I can see the order column in wordpress admin side but I'm not seeing the section I thought I would be be able to edit the order of my existing items. Everything is listed as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's from an element of Elementor, check it's settings.
Otherwise check in the Customize menu (depends on your theme)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).